# NodeJS promise .then finishes after loop is done?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have this code to check if a date in the database has an event. I want to set the hasEvent to true in the array of weeks and days. The problem is at the end it logs the same line 4 times. Why does it do this and how could I go about solving it?

This is the code I currently use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < weeks.length-1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < weeks[i].days.length-1; j++) {
        var datum = weeks[i].days[j];

        db.collection('events').doc(datum.year + "-" + datum.month + "-" + datum.day).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log(datum.year + "-" + datum.month + "-" + datum.day + " is true" + " i " + i + " j " + j);
                weeks[i].days[j].hasEvent = "true";
            }else{
                weeks[i].days[j].hasEvent = "false";
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It keeps returning ***2018-04-28 is true i 5 j 6***
I use the firestore database. the collection is called events. in events I have a document that has the date as name and in there I have some info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5351549

Comment: Use `let` for `i` and `j` and use `const` for `datum` instead of `var`, because var has (function scope) so it will keep the last value as the sync code is done, but const and let will have (block scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when your callback after your async calls is executed the loop is finished and at that moment `i` holds the value `weeks.length-2` and `j` the value `weeks[i].days.length-2`.

You could use [Array#forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead the for-loop to avoid that behaviour and make sure every async call is wrapped within its own function block that holds a proper index value.

Comment: Yeah I tought it would do something like that but I tought the .then would take the current I and J and wait for the promise to resolve before continue. but that is not the case appearantly.

Comment: @RamonRobben: Promises just provide a nice way to "manage" async "values". They don't change how the language works (i.e. they don't halt execution. If they did there wasn't a need for callbacks in the first place).

Comment: @FelixKling I mean currently I really dislike the way promises work. They seem to make everything so much harder. Maybe its because I do not fully understand how they work. or maybe they just are really difficult to work with.